# javascript problems when another javascript added

Tags: javascript

I have the following script that works fine until I add the other javascript below...

First Script in the header tags

```
function validateForm() {   
    var valid = true;
    var errMsg = "";
    var email = document.emailform.email.value;
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

   if(email.length <= 0) {
      valid = false;
      errMsg += "Email address is required.\n";
   } else {
      if (!filter.test(email)) {
         valid = false;
         errMsg += "Please provide a valid email address.\n";
      }
   }   
   if (errMsg.length > 0) {
      alert(errMsg);
      return false;
   }
}
```

and just before the closing tags I have...

```
$('#form').submit(validateForm);
```

The above works fine, except once I add the script below, `validateForm` no longer works. This following is added just before the closing body tags.

```
cbr202=Math.random()*10000000000000000;document.write('<scr'+'ipt language="JavaScript" src="http://example.com/landing.php?lpip=411&202cb='+cbr202+'" type="text/javascript"></scr' + 'ipt>');
```

I can't seem to figure out what's causing the issue. Hoping someone with experience can see the problem.

---

Solved: I figured it out... it was due to my own sloppiness. I should have the jquery event handler below the document.write script, not above it.

Comment: What is the *conflict*? Check your console for any error messages.

Comment: that second line writes out a link to another javascript file. What's in THAT javascript file?

Comment: @JonathanSampson That's the weird thing, there are no console error messages.

Comment: @user1373779 What then do you mean by *conflict*?

Comment: @JonathanSampson Maybe that's not proper terminology, but the first script works fine on it's own. Once I add the second script, it stops working. The second script works regardless.

Comment: Ugh! I feel like an ass... I moved the jquery .submit event handler below the second script and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a closing } to the function. That caused an error and resulted in any JS coming after that to not execute.

```
function validateForm() {   
    var valid = true;
    var errMsg = "";
    var email = document.emailform.email.value;
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

   if(email.length <= 0) {
      valid = false;
      errMsg += "Email address is required.\n";
   } else {
      if (!filter.test(email)) {
         valid = false;
         errMsg += "Please provide a valid email address.\n";
      }
   }   
   if (errMsg.length > 0) {
      alert(errMsg);
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it then already fail without the second script? I guess something else is wrong here.

Comment: Fair, but I just corrected what I saw. I think he thinks the first part works because he didn't test it, which he only did once he added the second part of the script. Just my guess though. But fair critique.

Comment: There's definitely something he/she is not telling us. The second part is perfectly valid.

Comment: whoops... yeah, I forgot to copy/paste the closing }. It's in the original script though.

Comment: @user1373779 : Did you retry with the new closed bracket code?

Comment: @StanislavPalatnik Yes, in actuality the actual live script included the closed bracket.

Answer (score 0):

the url generated by 
src="http://mysite.com/landing.php?lpip=411&202cb='+cbr202
does not exist. The browser tries to load the script from the url using a get request and fails.

Comment: You do know mysite.com is a placeholder for this question.

Comment: As Stanislav said, it's just a placeholder. The URL does exist, and that script is working. The issue is with the validateForm function, which works until the next script is added.

Comment: i know mysite.com is a placeholder... i am talking about the complete url which has a random number just generated as a part of it... the complete url can never exist beforehand

Answer (score 0):

```
cbr202=Math.random()*10000000000000000;
```

I think you need change code same below

```
var cbr202=Math.random()*10000000000000000;
```